# Usage of DRM Technology in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, drm

how can we use DRM technology to protect the content(like Audio,images....) in windows Phone 7,please share if there is any source code for that..

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 7 supports a version of the Silverlight 3 PlayReady DRM. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee923781(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

All XAPs uploaded to the marketplace, is encrypted with Microsoft's DRM.

Comment: Uuh, yes they are?  And they replaced the cracked certificates a half year ago.

Comment: Only devices running Mango support DRM'd XAPs and so it won't be enabled until (probably almost) everyone has upgraded as flipping the switch will prevent anyone with a pre-Mango device being able to get any new apps. (Apparently it's all or nothing.) I've just downloaded and opened a random XAP to confirm that it's still possible.

Answer (score 0):

Its not just audio and images, your code also needs to be protected as Xaps can be downloaded and decompiled.  You should obsficate your Xaps before uploading them to the marketplace.  This tool is provided free to WP7 developers:

http://www.preemptive.com/windowsphone7.html

After your done rename your XAP to .zip and use a decompiler to checkout how effective it is.
http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx

Read this thread on some of the problems and solutions
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/93104/557911.aspx